# Tkinter window that updates depending on the selection of the dropdown menu

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a GUI that updates once the choice in the dropdown menu is changed. The code below does this with a button, but the buttons and text that is called is not deleted every time the function is called.

Update window without an additional button

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

options = [
    "  ",
    "Expences",
    "Birds",
]


clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set(options[0])  # default value


drop = OptionMenu(app, clicked, *options)
drop.pack()


def show():
    click = clicked.get()

    if click == "Expences":
        def Expences():
            b2 = Button(app, text="YESSSS!!!")
            b2.pack()

        Expences()

    elif click == "Birds":
        def Birds():
            a3 = Label(app, text="Maybe")
            a3.pack()

        Birds()

    else:
        return


b1 = Button(app, text = "Click", command = show)
b1.pack()

app.minsize(400, 450)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `command=` in `OptionsMenu` to run function when it changes selection. Function will get selected value

```
import tkinter as tk

def show(click):
    if click == "Expences":
        b2 = tk.Button(app, text="YESSSS!!!")
        b2.pack()
    elif click == "Birds":
        a3 = tk.Label(app, text="Maybe")
        a3.pack()

# --- main ---

options = [
    "  ",
    "Expences",
    "Birds",
]

app = tk.Tk()

clicked = tk.StringVar()
clicked.set(options[0])  # default value

drop = tk.OptionMenu(app, clicked, *options, command=show)
drop.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

---

You can use `trace()` with `StringVar()` to check if it changed value

```
import tkinter as tk

def show(a, b, c):
    click = clicked.get()

    if click == "Expences":
        b2 = tk.Button(app, text="YESSSS!!!")
        b2.pack()
    elif click == "Birds":
        a3 = tk.Label(app, text="Maybe")
        a3.pack()

# --- main ---

options = [
    "  ",
    "Expences",
    "Birds",
]

app = tk.Tk()

clicked = tk.StringVar()
clicked.set(options[0])  # default value
clicked.trace('w', show)

drop = tk.OptionMenu(app, clicked, *options)
drop.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

---

`Tkinter` will not delete previous button or label. You would have to do it on your own. Or better create label and button at start but don't use `pack()` to show it . Later you can use `pack()` to show one of them and `pack_forget()` to remove other one.

```
import tkinter as tk

def show(a, b, c):

    click = clicked.get()

    if click == "Expences":
        b2.pack()
        a3.pack_forget()
    elif click == "Birds":
        a3.pack()
        b2.pack_forget()

# --- main ---

options = [
    "  ",
    "Expences",
    "Birds",
]

app = tk.Tk()

clicked = tk.StringVar()
clicked.set(options[0])  # default value
clicked.trace('w', show)

drop = tk.OptionMenu(app, clicked, *options)
drop.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(app, text="YESSSS!!!")
a3 = tk.Label(app, text="Maybe")

app.mainloop()
```